# text field length taking complete screen width

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I have a text field (mui) inside a div and the text field opens up on clicking an edit icon. Div has some content and has a display: flex. I want the text field to take the complete screen width in mobile view irrespective of div length.

How to do this. Please help.

I have tried width:100% in div and tried overriding mui width. Cannot use VW.

Tried adding a new class with a width of 100%. Cannot add width in px.

Comment: Why can't you use vw?

Comment: Want to use a better method than vw

Comment: Can you upload yuor CSS and HTML so we can have a look?

Comment: have you tried using position: relative?

Comment: Please can you share your code. We need to know what you've tried doing in order to help you